# How to put different background images for each page in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 pages in my rails website and I would like to put different background image in each of them. If I do

```
body {
   background-image: url("myimage.jpeg")
}
```

It will put the same background image on all of the pages. So I wrapped all the html code of each page in a main .class container and set the background image of the container which did the trick. But doing this leaves a little white space on the bottom part of the page and the background does not fully occupy the bottom part even when I do this

```
.wallpaperdiv {
      background-image: url("wallpaperbackground.jpeg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
            }
```

The first code that targets "body" instead of the class doesn't leave any white space. What would I have to do to remove the white space at the bottom?

Comment: `background-position: cover;` is not correct. Remove that and and the last one as well. `background-size: 100%;`  and then use `background-size: cover;` if you need to center the background then use `background-position: center  ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `class` attribute the `body` tag depending on the action it responds, for instance if you have a `foo`, `bar` and `meh` method in a controller `Main`, then you can do:

```
<body class="<%= params[:action] %>">
```

It'll produce a tag like `<body class="foo">` depending on the current action. So then you can create your CSS styles like:

```
body.foo { ... }
body.bar { ... }
body.meh { ... }
```

Note if you have more than one method with the same name, you'd probably need to add some extra info to the identifier.

Comment: Yes, this does work properly and is intuitive. Thank you for your contribution.